# How can I print a single row element in Python DictReader

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I've got a program to find DNA matches. We've been given a one line text file for finding the longest sequence of STR(Short Tandem Repeats) then match the result with a database which has been a .cvs file as below:

```
> name,AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG
> Albus,15,49,38,5,14,44,14,12 
> Draco,9,13,8,26,15,25,41,39
> Ginny,37,47,10,23,5,48,28,23
> Harry,46,49,48,29,15,5,28,40
```

After getting results for longest sequence amounts(as integer) I'm trying to find a match in this cvs file and print the value in the first column (name) when I found the matching numbers of STR. I'm checking the program with `print()` and it prints 'no match' until the matched name then stops with below error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "dna.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
    File "dna.py", line 27, in main
    print(row[0])
KeyError: 0
```

My program probably finds the match but can't print out than exits. Could you please help me? TIA

```
def main():
    for i in SEQ.keys():
        SEQ[i] = find_longest_sequence(i)
    print(SEQ.items())
    with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
        db = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in db:
            if int(row['AGATC']) == SEQ['AGATC'] and int(row['AATG']) == SEQ['AATG'] and int(row['TATC']) == SEQ['TATC']:
                print(row[0])
            else:
                print("No match")
```

Comment: have you tried print(row['name']) ?

Comment: @rodvictor yes I've tried but it didn't work either. Now I'm creating a list of dictionaries for eash row of cvs file and I'll compare the result by comparing two dictionaries. Hope it works

Comment: @rodvictor definetly not working as the result only contain STR numbers, cvs file has also name row :/ can I compare the values of dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the data you provided and made a test.csv

```
name,AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG
Albus,15,49,38,5,14,44,14,12 
Draco,9,13,8,26,15,25,41,39
Ginny,37,47,10,23,5,48,28,23
Harry,46,49,48,29,15,5,28,40
```

Then tested with the folowing code (py csv-test.py test.csv):

```
import csv
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
    db = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in db:
        if int(row['AGATC']) == 15:
            print(row['name'])
```

And the result was "Albus".

PS. With:

```
print(row[0])
```

I get the same KeyError as you do.

Do I miss something?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to extract one item as you suggested, by the way it works good on my code too. So I had to implement a different algorithm for the solution. The only thing left is to find a way to compare the values of  this dictionary with the ordered dictionaries in database. Thanks for the answer. I'm going to add this to my snippets.